# Unable to arrange evenly scattered information from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to arrange some uniformly scattered information from a spreadsheet to another. The information I'm interested in is in `Sheet2` and I wish to place them in a customized manner in `Sheet1`.

I've tried with:

```
Sub ArrangeInformation()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, cel As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set tws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each cel In ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)
        tws.Range(cel(1, 1).Address) = cel
    Next cel
End Sub
```

The above script just replicates the same information in `Sheet1` how they are in `Sheet2`.

Data in `Sheet2`:

[image]

How I like to arrange them in `Sheet1`:

[image]

> ***How can I arrange those information in sheet1?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can use some math to get the correct columns and rows:

```
Sub ArrangeInformation()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    Dim tws As Worksheet
    Set tws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim i As Long
    i = 0

    Dim j As Long
    j = 0

    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        If cel <> "" Then
            tws.Cells(Int(i / 4) + 1, ((j) Mod 4) + 1) = cel
            i = i + 1
            j = j + 1
        End If

    Next cel
End Sub
```

In the math the `4`s are the number of items in each pattern

The INT will increase by `1` every four rounds and the MOD will repeat 1,2,3,4 every 4 rounds.

---

Just because:

this can be done with a formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,INT(ROW(1:1)-1)/5+MOD((COLUMN(A:A)-1),5)+1)
```

where the 2 `5`s are the pattern and the `+1` is the starting row of the data.

Put that in sheet1 A1 and copy over and down.

Comment: Hi @Scott, is it possible that you make a one liner comment as to how that math functioned. Sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe use `Resize` to transfer your data:

```
Sub Test()

Dim lr As Long, x As Long, y As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

y = 1
lr = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For x = 1 To lr Step 5
    ws2.Cells(y, 1).Resize(, 4) = Application.Transpose(ws1.Cells(x, 1).Resize(4))
    y = y + 1
Next x

End Sub
```

---

And propbably faster, you could assign your range to an array:

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr As Variant
Dim lr As Long, x As Long, y As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

y = 1
lr = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
arr = ws1.Range("A1:A" & lr)
For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) Step 5
    ws2.Cells(y, 1).Resize(, 4) = Array(arr(x, 1), arr(x + 1, 1), arr(x + 2, 1), arr(x + 3, 1))
    y = y + 1
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: This is the very approach I wished to comply with in the first place. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to manage which rows and columns you write to inside your loop. Something like:

```
Sub ArrangeInformation()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, cel As Range

    'New variables to manage rows and columns to write to
    Dim writecol as integer, writeRow as integer

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set tws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Start in Row 1, Column 1
    writeRow = 1
    writeCol = 1
    For Each cel In ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)


        tws.Range(writeRow, writeCol) = cel     

        'Next Column, or reset to 1 and iterate rows
        If writeCol = 4 Then
            writeCol = 1
            writeRow = writeRow + 1
        Else
            writeCol = writeCol + 1         
        End If

    Next cel
End Sub
```